# How to replace ngAnnotate to babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate in grunt task

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, bundling-and-minification, grunt-contrib-uglify, gruntfile

I am using angular js (1.6),I have following task in grunt for minification angular modules

```
ngAnnotate: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
      src: '*.js',
      dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
    }]
  }
}
```

But above task not support ES2015 and ES2016 features
How to add  **babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate** in **grunt** task in i.e.grunt file

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, install the plugin:

```
npm install babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate --save-dev
```

then there are two ways:

1. follow the readme, add the plugin into .babelrc file:

   {
   "plugins": ["angularjs-annotate"]
   }
2. in grunt.initConfig, set this plugin at babel part, like:

   babel: {
   options: {
       sourceMap: true,
       presets: [@babel/preset-env],
       plugins: ['angularjs-annotate']
   },
   files: {
     expand: true, 
     ...
   }
   }

any of them work.

my environment:

1. grunt-cli v1.3.2
2. grunt v1.0.3